# Method doesnt exist or incorrect signature in Test class

Tags: unit-test

In component side,

```
<aura:attribute name="weekDaysBool" type="Object" default="[false, false, false, false, false]"/>
```

In Apex class I have passed the "weekDaysBool" variable like array of boolean

```
 @AuraEnabled
  public static List < EventObj > insertEvents(String sEventObj, String 
  sObjectName, String titleField, String startDateTimeField, String 
  endDateTimeField, String descriptionField, String userField, string 
  whatIdField, string whoIdField, Boolean[] weekDays) {
 }
```

In test class,I need to cover "weekDaysBool" variable using List of boolean variable

```
 List<Boolean> booleanList=new    List<Boolean>();booleanList.add(false);
  booleanList.add(false);
  booleanList.add(false);
  booleanList.add(false);
  booleanList.add(false);
s360_AnyEventCalCtrl.insertEvents('{"title":"dasdsad","startDateTime":"2017-04-26T17:00:00-07:00","endDateTime":"2017-04-26T19:00:00-07:00","description":"asdasd"}', 'Event', 'Subject', 'Title', 'StartDateTime', 'EndDateTime', 'Description', 'OwnerId', 'WhatID', 'whoId', booleanlist);
```

But it shows following error:

Method doesnt  exist or incorrect signature

Complete error Message:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void insertEvents(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, List) from the type s360_AnyEventCalCtrl

Comment: Paste complete error message.

Comment: I updated question .please check it

Comment: it should work....what if you initialize as this ...        Boolean[] q1 = new Boolean[]{false,false,false};

Comment: its also not working.i have tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are passing one extra parameter. You might want to pass any one of them.

```
'Subject', 'Title',
```

As your method accept 9 String parameter while you are passing 10 parameters. So remove one parameter.